# Mathematically express length of $n$-tuple

Tags: notation

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) says "An $n$-tuple is a sequence (or ordered list) of $n$ elements, where $n$ is a non-negative integer."

so I have a $n$-tuple $m$, what of $m$ is $n$?

If I write $f(m)=n$, which function should $f$ be? Is there already a mathematical notation available?

Comment: What about "dimension" ?

Comment: As kind of implied in K.defaoite's answer, you wouldn't normally have a tuple out of the blue without declaring a name for its length at the same time. Like, at worst maybe something like "let $x_i\in\mathbb R^{n_i}$ for $1\le i\le k$".

Answer (score 2):

An $n$ tuple comes from the $n$ fold Cartesian product of a set with itself. That is to say given $x_1 \in S,...,x_n\in S$, this is equivalent to
$$\underline{x}=(x_1,...,x_n)\in \underbrace{S \times {}\dotsm{} \times S}_{n \text{ times}}$$
Which is often denoted
$$\underline{x}\in S^n$$
It is technically incorrect to talk about the dimension of $\underline{x}$, i.e the expression $\dim{\underline{x}}=n$ it is however correct to say $\dim(S^n)=n$ but this is redundant because the $n$ superscript already implies the dimension of the set.

Answer (score 1):

Following the title of your question, I would call it the *length* of the tuple, in analogy with the length of a word of a free monoid, since a word is an ordered sequence of letters. As for notation, the length of a word $u$ is usually denoted by $|u|$.